# Combine/retrieve typescript declaration files

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a [TypeScript typings project](https://github.com/phreed/typed-npm-webgme) containing several *.d.ts files.
This is a set of 'global' declarations (i.e. named modules).
I use typings to pull the declaration files from that typings project into a TypeScript project.

```
typings install github:phreed/typed-npm-webgme -SG
```

The resulting typings/globals/index.d.ts only contains the file identified as the "main" in [typings.json](https://github.com/phreed/typed-npm-webgme/blob/master/typings.json).
I expect it to include (concatenate) all of content of the "files" appearing in the [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/phreed/typed-npm-webgme/blob/master/tsconfig.json).

How do I cause typings/globals/index.d.ts to contain the concatenation of the *.d.ts files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 'files' field where additional declaration files can be indicated.
Here is an example of the 'typings.json' file.
`json
{
    "name": "foo",
    "main": "foo.d.ts",
    "files":    [
        "./bar.d.ts",
        "./baz.d.ts",
        "./froz.d.ts",
        "./fig.d.ts"],
    "global": true,
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "globalDependencies": {
        "q": "registry:dt/q#0.0.0+20160613154756"
    },
    "globalDevDependencies": {
    }
}`

The git repository (assume github) holds these *.d.ts files separately. 
When installed, using 

`typings install github:foo/foo --save --global`

- retrieves and concatenates the '*.d.ts' files into 'typings/globals/foo/index.d.ts'.
- updates 'typings/globals/foo/typings.json' with the package typings information.
- updates 'typings/index.d.ts' with '/// <reference path="globals/foo/index.d.ts" />
- updates 'globalDependencies' in 'typings.json' with "foo": "github:foo/foo"